# rails 3 with multiple mysql connections

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails 3 application and I have two mysql servers, both of which can handle mysql queries. Traditionally, rails 3 has maintained one persistent database connection. But I was wondering how one can 
A) define multiple mysql connections
B) automatically load balance the mysql queries amongst multiple mysql connections

Thanks

Comment: You would add the load-balancing in some sort of in between layer, not in the client-application.

Comment: But how will that layer interface with ActiveRecord which uses a mysql connection to update model data.

Comment: It should completly transparent to the client-application: see: http://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian